A question about dice combinations - cube digit pairs
This is question number 90 on Project Euler.
I solved it using a computer approach and my answer was 1217, which is correct. I want to solve it using mathematics, but I am facing a problem because I don't have enough skills in combinations.
I think:
If we have {0, 8} on the first dice, the second dice must have {1, 4}.
Each dice must contain at least one of 6 or 9, so the dice combinations would be {0, 8, 6-9} for the first one and {1, 4, 6-9} for the second one.
We suppose that the first dice has a 2, so the second one must have a 5.
Finally, we can have any number as the two remaining digits. My mathematical method is to $ \binom{2}{1}$ choose 1 out of 2 to determine 6-9, choose 1 out of 2 to determine 2 or 5, and choose 2 out of 6 to determine the remaining two sides.
And next multiple two dice.
However, this gives me the wrong answer. I know I made a mistake in solving this and I would appreciate it if somebody could point it out.
Another way is to calculate all possibilities and then subtract all the conditions that I don't want, but I want to solve it using the above method.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

If you switch the two dice, does that make a new arrangement?

please calculate both

You're not properly accounting for the fact that you have 12 spaces and 9 numbers, which means several numbers will appear on both dice. (Since we don't use 7, we can duplicate up to 4 numbers.)
Your argument starts with "If we have 0 on the first dice, the second dice must have {1, 4} " (let's ignore 8 for now), but that claim is not true. EG we could have {0, 1} on the first dice and {0, 4} on the second dice.
The version that is true is "If 0 is not on the second dice, then we must have 0 on the first dice, and {1, 4} on the second dice".
Likewise for "We suppose that the first dice has a 2, so the second one must have a 5", the correct version is "If 5 is not on the first dice, then 2 is on the first dice and 5 is on the second dice".
FWIW I don't see a nice mathematical argument to this, that doesn't result in a ton of case checking.

Thank you for your response. Can you please provide more assistance
1// We have 10 numbers  (from 0 to 9 (inclusive))
2//Repetitive numbers can be present in different dice, but cannot be repeated in the same dice.
3//My first argument states that if one dice has 0, the other must have 1-4. This is necessary for creating square numbers such as 01 and 04. If the first dice has {0,1}, we cannot form a square number because we can only choose one number from each dice.

Therefore, for a correct answer, one dice must have 0, while the other must have 1-4. It is possible for both dice to have 0 and still form a correct answer, but only one dice needs to have 1-4 on the other side.
For a correct answer, the first dice should contain {0,8,6-9,2,X1,X2}, where X1 and X2 can be {1,3,4,5,6-9,7}.
The second dice should contain {1,4,6-9,5,Y1,Y2}, where Y can be {0,2,3,6-9,7,8}.

@Arthur_D 1/ But 6 and 9 are the same number, so we only have 9 "numbers". EG instead of writing it as 6-9, I'm only writing it as 6. 2/ Agreed about how repetition works. 3/ Read my solution. I gave you an example where no dice had both 1 and 4. This can occur when 0 is repeated across both dice.
